# No output is displaying, cannot find error (Java)

Tags: java, runtime-error, output

I am trying to write a Tester and a class that can solve quadratic function.

If you are unfamiliar with quadratic function, or need a reminder, here is a quick link to it's Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function

My tester seems to work fine, however whenever I try to call the method, the program stops, and it doesn't display the output of the method (which is supposed to display the answer).

I am not skilled enough to find out if the error is within the class or the tester.

**Tester:**

```
/**
 * A Tester to use to solve quadratic formula. Enter your values
 * when prompted, and the answer will be displayed on screen.
 * 
 * @author (Austin C.) 
 * @version (1.0.0)
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class C_tester
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter the coefficents in the form of the following:\n1.A\n2.B\n3.C");

    System.out.print("Enter the number for A:");
    int a = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number for B:");
    int b = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number for C:");
    int c = kb.nextInt();

    QuadraticFunction.quadratic(a,b,c);
    }
}
```

**Quadratic Function Class:**

```
/**
 * @Params: you must enter the coefficents, A, B, and C, and the program will calculate them to find the answer
 * to a quadratic forumla. coefficents must be integers or doubles. 
 * 
 * @author (Austin C.) 
 * @version (1.0.0)
 */
public class QuadraticFunction
{
    public void QuadraticFunction()
    {
    }

    public static double quadratic(double a, double b, double c)
    {
    double topPos;
    double topNeg;
    double bot;

    topPos = -b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2.0)  - 4 * a * c);
    topNeg = -b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2.0)  - 4 * a * c);
    bot = 2*a;

    double ansPos = topPos/bot;
    double ansNeg = topNeg/bot;

    return ansPos + ansNeg;
    }
}
```

Any help to find the error myself or find it for me is greatly appreciated. Also, if you find a more efficient way to do this, please share! I am always looking for more efficient ways to write code.

If the question is unclear, please say so and I can redo it in a more understandable way.

Comment: It works just fine, only that your tester calls `QuadraticFunction.quadratic(a,b,c);` but doesn't print the returned result...

Comment: No output is displaying because you do not print the result :) `System.out.println(QuadraticFunction.quadratic(a,b,c));`

Answer (score 1):

`quadratic` has return type `double`, and there are no print statements in the method. What this means is that it should return a value, but there is no reason that value should be printed. You can fix this by assigning the function result to a variable, and then adding a statement to print it to screen, like so:

```
double answer = QuadraticFunction.quadratic(a,b,c);
System.out.println(answer);
```

Also, you should note that a quadratic equation can have 2 real roots (possibly both the same), so you should be returning an array of `doubles` rather than a single `double` which is the sum of those 2 roots.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect it to print? You never tell the program to print anything. You can have it print the result to stdout by changing the last line in the tester to `System.out.println(QuadraticFunction.quadratic(a,b,c));` if the program stops and there was no stack trace printed it means that it was executed succesfully